# how to refresh template after ajax call

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I have a form that contains two select inputs one is for categories and the other for sub categories the form should work like this user should choose an option in the categories and based on that option the sub category options should be updated with new values. but for some reason the sub category options aren't updating

template dashboard.html

```
{% block body %}
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
            <select id="list">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your Category</option>
                <option value="education">University/College</option>
                <option value="hospital">Hospital</option>
                <option value="business">Business Organizations</option>
            </select>
            <label>Categories</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
            <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your Category</option>
            {% for d in data %}
                <option value="">{{ d.username }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <label>Sub Categories</label> 
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#list').change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/dashboard/',
                data: {
                    category: $('#list').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def dashboard(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            category = request.POST['category']
            #Here i am using User table because category table is empty
            data = User.objects.all()
            print(data)
            return render(request, 'usecases/dashboard.html', {'data': data})
        else:
            return render(request, 'usecases/dashboard.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is  your subcategories where I just add an id `#sub_categories`

```
<select id='sub_categories'>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your Category</option>
    {% for d in data %}
        <option value="">{{ d.username }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<label>Sub Categories</label>
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/dashboard/',
    data: {
        category: $('#list').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
     },
     success:function(response){
         $('#sub_categories').replaceWith($("#sub_categories",response))
     }
 });
```

Comment: try debugging with your browser, does Django receive the ajax call?

Comment: yes it does when I print(category) in the view.py it shows the value in the console

Comment: so now debug your js file, add `alert('Test')` inside ajax success, just to see whether it'll be triggered

Comment: it didn't alert

Comment: debug with your browser, take a look at your console, to see the status of the request: 200, 500

Comment: the alert worked after refreshing the development server for five times when i switched it to the replace with methods it didn't change the options

Comment: Note that I add an ID to `select`... if you still don't see anything, try `alert($('#sub_categories',data).html())` it should alert the new html

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.success ((index):116)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

And yes i noticed the id in the select input

Comment: sorry, i would say `alert($('#sub_categories',response).html())`

Comment: the values appeared in the alert function

Comment: so, that means, this is wrong in your code, make sure, you got it well. `$('#sub_categories').replaceWith($("#sub_categories",response));`
`replaceWith()` with capitale W  and  make sure the ID is correct

Comment: I figured out whats wrong, I used unordered list to render the value and it worked. I think there is a problem with the materialize library specifically in the select input. and also I really appreciate your help

Comment: so basically #ajax can do what you want,